# Sliding Page Transitions

Tags: jquery, transition, sliding

I want to have a site that slides between pages but everything I've found regarding sliding page transitions is for single page sites. For certain SEO and marketing purposes I would rather have multiple pages that would slide on page load is this possible with jQuery or some other language?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post the entire originating html to the new page (probably encoded in a form value), then on load of the new page, actually show this original html at first and then slide in the new page. Might be slow though.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this a little more could I not just position a wrapper with all the content in it off the edge at like -3000px then on page load animate it into view and when and link is clicked just send it off on the other side?

Comment: I guess this would be pretty bad for anyone who had jquery disabled in browser but I could also potentially do the positioning with jquery and it would look fine to all users